# How to reliably reject out-of-gramar words in PocketSphinx

Tags: android, cmusphinx

I am using PocketsphinxDemo successfully on Android. I have a very limited set of words to be recognized, say 3 different words.
I currently get lots of false positives - while talking, Pocketsphinx recognizes one of my 3 words although they have not been spoken.

As I can't find any reference for the parameters pocketsphinx is using, here's my question:

Is there a parameter to make Pocketsphinx react more restrictive?

I want it to return its recognition guess only if Pocketsphinx is highly "sure" to match the correct word.

Here are the default parameters I am currently using:

```
c.setFloat("-samprate", 8000.0);
c.setInt("-maxhmmpf", 2000);
c.setInt("-maxwpf", 10);
c.setInt("-pl_window", 2);
c.setBoolean("-backtrace", true);
c.setBoolean("-bestpath", false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for simple rejection of out-of-grammar words in pocketpshinx right now, though it might appear soon. For some more information see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qcan_pocketsphinx_reject_out-of-grammar_words_and_noises

You still can emulate out-of-grammar words with phone loop and that can give you some rejection. For that you need to construct grammar in a special way and add garbage phones there. For more details see

http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/1c6cb941/?limit=50#efa9

The grammar formatting is screwed there, but the idea is simple, you just add phones in the loop:

```
 <result> = word1 | word2 | (phone1 | phone2 | .... | phone 39)*
```

For IPhone Openears implement a special module for rejection, it's not a part of main distribution:

http://www.politepix.com/rejecto/

Comment: Thanks you! I'd like to try that. I currently use lmtool online to convert my grammar into lm/dict files. Is there something similar for JSGF grammars?

Comment: how can I feed JSGF grammar to pocketsphinx?

Comment: pocketphinx_continuous -jsgf grammar.jsgf

Comment: Same on android, the grammar is configured in RecognizerTask.java

Comment: ok, got it working thanks to http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/49e34dff/
but it doesn't recognize anything but "GARBAGE" ;-)

Comment: Reduce word insertion probability (-wip parameter, make it smaller) in order to reduce amount of garbage phones in results and increase amount of words.